# Error while calling a function that is not payable

Tags: remix, erc-20, payable

I was trying to execute the below contract and calling the function approveOperator but it says, "The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.", even though the function is not payable.
Please help

````
contract Desurance is ERC20{


   address public moderator;

   mapping(address => address) private userNominee;

   uint public subscriptionFees;

   uint private contractCreationTimestamp;    
   
   struct User{
       bool UserRegistered;
       uint userStartTime;
       address[] ERCTokens;
       uint[] balances;
   }



   User[] public users;

   mapping(address=>uint) public usersIndex;

   mapping(uint => address[]) private UsersOnSingleDay;


   constructor(uint _subFees) ERC20("Desurance coin", "DRC"){
       moderator = msg.sender;
       subscriptionFees = _subFees;
       contractCreationTimestamp = block.timestamp;
       _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
   }
   uint oneminute = 60;


   function timePassed() private view returns(uint){
       uint time = block.timestamp - contractCreationTimestamp;
       time = time/(60); 
       return time;
   }
   function addUser() public payable {
       require(msg.value > subscriptionFees);
       User memory newuser;
       newuser.UserRegistered = true;
       newuser.userStartTime = block.timestamp;
       users.push(newuser);
       usersIndex[msg.sender]=users.length - 1;
       uint time = timePassed();
       UsersOnSingleDay[time].push(msg.sender);
   }



   function addNominee(address _nominee) public {
       require(_nominee != address(0));
       uint x = usersIndex[msg.sender];
       require(x < users.length);
       //User memory userTemp = users[x];
       userNominee[msg.sender] = _nominee;
   }

   function approveOperator(address[] memory tokenAddress) public {

       uint x = usersIndex[msg.sender];
       require(x < users.length);
       User storage userNow = users[x];
       uint balance;
       bool final1;
       uint len = tokenAddress.length;
       for(uint i=0; i < len ; i++){
       require(ERC20(tokenAddress[i]).balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0);
       balance = ERC20(tokenAddress[i]).balanceOf(msg.sender);
       final1 = ERC20(tokenAddress[i]).approve(moderator,balance);
       //address a1 = tokenAddress[i];
       userNow.ERCTokens.push(tokenAddress[i]);
       userNow.balances.push(balance);
       //return final1;
       }
   }


   //function transferFun

   //function 

   function transferFundsToNominee() public{
       require(msg.sender == moderator);
       require(block.timestamp > oneminute);
       uint minuteIndex = (block.timestamp - oneminute)/(60);

       address[] memory usersTransfer = UsersOnSingleDay[minuteIndex];

       uint arrayLength = usersTransfer.length;

       for(uint i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
           uint x=usersIndex[usersTransfer[i]];
           User memory userNow = users[x];
           address finalNominee = userNominee[usersTransfer[i]];
           uint balanceLength = userNow.balances.length;
           for(uint j=0;j<balanceLength;j++){
               address tokenNow = userNow.ERCTokens[j];
               uint balanceNow = userNow.balances[j];
               ERC20(tokenNow).transferFrom(usersTransfer[i], finalNominee,balanceNow);

           }

       }

   }


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It works if you inject into web3. From Remix, go into `DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTION` section and choose `Inject Web3` from Environment dropdown. At this point, connect your metamask wallet and deploy it on any testnet (Rinkeby, Ropsten, Goerli or Kovan) and deploy your smart contract. Now you can call your smart contract functions.